# WordPress Yoast Focus Keyword not updating

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, yoast

I am trying to update Yoast Focus Keyword field programmatically in WordPress plugin. But unfortunately, I cannot see the desired result on screen.

Could you please help me with this?

Here is the code I am using

```
$updated_title = update_post_meta($post_id, '_yoast_wpseo_focuskw', $metatitle);
```

Thank You all for helping me.

Comment: hey are you able to solve it? it does not seems to work form me too

Comment: Hi, No still not working for me.

Comment: it won't work unless it's executed :)..with some action , it works